# Issue in streaming mov file in browsers using quicktime player plugin

Tags: html, video-streaming, quicktime, .mov

I am embedding .mov file in the webpage using following HTML code

```
 <embed border="1" 
        autoplay="false" 
        cache="false" 
        loop="false" 
        setcontrollervisible="true" 
        scale="tofit" 
        src="movie.mov" 
        controller="true" 
        qtsrc="movie.mov" 
        type="video/quicktime">    
 </embed>
```

In this case the video is first totally downloaded and then played in browser. Forsome videos size is around 100MB and so it takes huge amount of time to first download and then play.

Is there any way to force browser to only stream video and not to download and play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was issue with my video file.
"The MOOV atom, an important piece of metadata needed to make it progressively playable, was located at the end of the file. It needed to be at the beginning".

I used "qt-faststart" program to arrange atoms and it is working.